# dfa transition function

Tags: c++, data-structures, complexity-theory, automata, finite-automata

i'm looking to create a transition function of an automata with a O(1)  , complexity . I was thinking of using a HashMap or a Binary tree .
Are those idea any good ? an have you some suggestions .
Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need a constant evaluation of the transition function, no searching is permitted. This means that only a two-dimensional array (where one index is the current state and the other the read letter) can be used.